# MySQL CHAR() Function and UTF8 Output?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, escaping, string-literals

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.1.41    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select char(0x00FC);
+--------------+
| char(0x00FC) |
+--------------+
| ?            |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expecting actual utf8 character --> " ü " instead of " ? "  Tried char(0x00FC using utf8) also, but no go.

Using mysql version 5.1.41

Been allover the Google, cannot find anything on this.  The MySQL docs simply say that multibyte output is expected on values greater than 255, after mysql version 5.0.14.

Thanks

Comment: What character set is your shell using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing UTF-8 with Unicode.

0x00FC is the **Unicode** code point for ü:

```
mysql> select char(0x00FC using ucs2);
+----------------------+
| char(0x00FC using ucs2) |
+----------------------+
| ü                   | 
+----------------------+
```

In **UTF-8** encoding, 0x00FC [is represented by two bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#Description):

```
mysql> select char(0xC3BC using utf8);
+-------------------------+
| char(0xC3BC using utf8) |
+-------------------------+
| ü                      | 
+-------------------------+
```

UTF-8 is merely a way of **encoding** Unicode characters in binary form. It is meant to be space efficient, which is why ASCII characters only take a single byte, and iso-8859-1 characters such as ü only take two bytes. Some other characters take three or four bytes, but they are much less common.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I have been looking for the "using" clause for the last two hours, not knowing what it was called! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Martin & @Cyberdancer91 : To clarify, UTF-8 was _not_ meant to save space (a very common misunderstanding). It was meant to be ASCII compatible, a way for systems to support Unicode without breaking any existing text / config files, which would've required TONS of testing/fixing time. The first 128 characters saving 1 byte is just a side-effect; 63k out of 65k BMP characters take 1 EXTRA byte. Please see the two footnotes (and other relevant info) in my post: https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/09/28/native-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-savior-false-prophet-or-both/ , and my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384387/577765):

1. You can use an "introducer" instead of the `CHAR()` function. To do this, you specify the encoding, *prefixed with an underscore*, before the code point:

   ```
   _utf16 0xFC
   ```

   or:

   ```
   _utf16 0x00FC
   ```
2. If the goal is to specify the code point instead of the encoded byte sequence, then you need to use an encoding in which the code point value just happens to be the encoded byte sequence. For example, as shown in Martin's answer, `0x00FC` is both the code point value for `ü` and the encoded byte sequence for `ucs2` / `utf16` (they are effectively the same encoding for BMP characters, but I prefer to use "utf16" as it is consistent with "utf8" and "utf32", consistent in the "utf" theme).

   But, `utf16` only works for BMP characters (code points U+0000 - U+FFFF) in terms of specifying the code point value. If you want a Supplementary Character, then you will need to use the `utf32` encoding. Not only does `_utf32 0xFC` return `ü`, but:

   ```
   _utf32 0x1F47E
   ```

   returns: 👾

For more details on these options, plus Unicode escape sequences for other languages and platforms, please see my post:

[Unicode Escape Sequences Across Various Languages and Platforms (including Supplementary Characters)](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/06/26/unicode-escape-sequences-across-various-languages-and-platforms-including-supplementary-characters/)