# SELECT CHAR(224 USING UTF8) returning nothing?

Tags: mysql, function, char

Consider this simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT CHAR(224 USING UTF8)
```

This isn't returning anything for me. I would expect it to return à.

I tried specifying a collation:

```
SELECT CHAR(224 USING UTF8) COLLATE UTF8_BIN
```

But that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following

```
SET CHARSET utf8;
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT char(0x00E0 using ucs2);
```

Comment: Well, I actually need to be able to convert an *arbitrary* Unicode point to a character. The character à was just an example.

Comment: I don't actually know, but the character sets are very very similar... I've always used SET NAMES utf8 and did all inserts, selects using directly the data I wanted, I write all html with charset set to utf8 and thus everything works from the start

Comment: I use those in all my php programming as the first lines when connecting to database, they allow to directly insert any data sent to me via get, post or ajax requests

Comment: found another stack overflow question which will give you a hopefully easier to understand answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384129/mysql-char-function-and-utf8-output