# mysql Incorrect string value error in stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

[Incorrect string value: '\xE8' for column 'P10' at row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h0rw.png)

I'm making stored procedure for EMS RFID communication and return packet to c# application. But it shows error like image on P10 character. What is wrong?? First version was c# code. I'm trying move to mysql stored procedure.

please any suggestion.

(I already checked characterset is utf8)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetRFIDWriteCommand`(`Param1` VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT
BEGIN
    DECLARE P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10 CHAR;
    DECLARE TIMEOUT INT;
    DECLARE RET TEXT;

    SET TIMEOUT = 1000;
    SET P0 = char(2); # &H2     STX 
    SET P1 = char(2); #  &H2 
    SET P2 = char(0); #  &H0   
    SET P3 = char(LENGTH(Param1) + 7);
    SET P4 = char(6); #  &HD         #write command
    SET P5 = char(0);
    SET P6 = char(0); #  brStart_Add
    SET P7 = char(0);
    SET P8 = char(LENGTH(Param1)); #  brLength        #length (=100)
    SET P9 = char(3);
    SET P10 = char(232); # <=== ERROR POINT

    SET RET = CONCAT(P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,char(3));

    return RET;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution!!

```
char(0x00FC using ucs2)
```

just use like this

char(HexValue using ucs2)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384387/1038996